# Spring boot oauth2, how to retrieve the initial request before authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

i am using the following depdendencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

i enabled oauth2 for the endpoint `/login`, now when i access the url `/login?foo=bar` after successful authentication i get redirected to path `/`. i understand i can set the redirect url with `ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setLocation()` method, but i want to be able to redirect to page success.html with query param `foo` with its value `bar`, something like `/success.html?foo=bar`, how can i retrieve the request which was initially made to the login endpoint before authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the issue, the default behaviour for spring oauth2 client is to redirect to the protected resource, in my case i restricted `/foo/login` endpoint but started the authentication from `/login` endpoint, that was the reason spring didnt redirect to the protected resource.